# Can i use an @Input() in Angular with more types?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a parent component that has to pass an object in @Input to the child component, but the object may not always be the same. For example, can i have:

```
@Input() obj: string | number;
```

?

In my specific case i have two different objects as possibles inputs:

```
@Input() obj: AppDetail | AbsDetail;
```

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: have you tried it? did it work?

Comment: yes, you can, and it is fine doing so. Just make sure that you handle AppDetail vs AbsDetail differently in all the correct places

Comment: @SalminSkenderovic I was trying, but i'm not sure that this is the correct way. VScode doesn't marks it as an error, but if i try so, then with obj i can just use the attributes that are the same in both AppDetail and AbsDetail. To specify, AppDetail and AbsDetail has both fields like id: number, startTime: Date, endTime: Date, and i can reach those, but the other fields, different from one to another class, aren't reachable.

Comment: @depperm yes, i tried. VS doesn't mark it as an error, but now it seems like i can't reach all the fields of both classes. I wonder if it's possible somehow or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by your comment you have issues reaching fields that do not overlap in the types. There are three ways around this:

1. use an `@Input` for every different type. But that's not your question :)
2. use `&` instead of `|` for your `@Input` type:

```js
@Input() obj: AppDetail & AbsDetail;
```

It's the quickest, but not the type safest solution, so use with caution. This will do an [intersect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of your type objects

3. You assert first what type it is before continuing in your code. For example:

```js
interface AppDetail {
  id: string;
  details: string;
}

interface AbsDetail {
  code: number;
  details: string;
}

function isAppDetail(obj: AppDetail | AbsDetail): obj is AppDetail {
  return obj.hasOwnProperty('id');
}

function isABsDetail(obj: AppDetail | AbsDetail): obj is isABsDetail {
  return obj.hasOwnProperty('code');
}

@Component({/*...*/})
export class DetailComponent {
  @Input() obj: AppDetail | AbsDetail;

  doSomethingWithObj(): void {
    if (isAppDetail(obj)) {
      // here you can access obj.id without a typescript error
    } else {
      // here you can access obj.code without a typescript error
      // because it's not AppDetail, the compiler knows that it should be AbsDetail
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
get dtype(){
if(obj instanceof AppDetail){
    return 1
}

if(obj instanceof AbsDetail ){
    return 2
}
}
```

hope it helps